# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment. EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java

The below error I get after I run my stand alone application developed in JAVA. Please help

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#  EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION (0xc0000096) at pc=0x04730008, pid=1872, tid=2248
# JRE version: 6.0_30-b12
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.5-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x04730008
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

I get this error after I run my stand alone application developed in JAVA.

Please help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140030/possible-causes-of-java-vm-exception-access-violation

Comment: We need some code to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this type of error comes when the threads are not managed well. So, you can manage your thread or you can share your code then i can do anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Exception Access Violation Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500378/exception-access-violation-java)

According to this thread it's most likely your app trying to access or free memory it doesn't belong to.