# Selenium + java = crashing "fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a machine where I have been running Selenium automation scripts for a while now.  Most recently, I have been running two different suites each day for months, one mvn, one ant.  Nothing has changed.  Now they almost always crash.  I have tried re-installing java.  I updated the selenium jar.  I have the most up to date chromewebdriver.  It crashes at a different step each time.  Sometimes it crashes and leaves behind the following message below in cmd prompt window.  Sometimes the machine actually goes down and comes back up when this automation suite is running.

```
fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000002990719, pid=4000, t
id=1852

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_11-b12) (build 1.8.0_11-b12)

Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.11-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64
compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
v  ~StubRoutines::atomic_cmpxchg_long

Core dump written. Default location: c:\Selenium\Projects\foobar\hs_err_p
id4000.mdmp

An error report file with more information is saved as:
c:\Selenium\Projects\foobar\hs_err_pid4000.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp


Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5:43.270s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jul 29 08:51:02 EDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/113M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
12.4:test (default-test) on project foobar: Execution default-test
of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The f
orked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit cal
led ? -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutio
nException
```

The dump log hs_err_pid4000.mdmp shows:

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000223c800):  GCTaskThread [stack:     0x0000000012150000,0x0000000012250000] [id=1852]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffffffffff

Registers:
RAX=0x0000800080000000, RBX=0x0000800080000000, RCX=0x0000800080002000,     RDX=0x00000000124f15c0
RSP=0x000000001224f5a0, RBP=0x0000000054fc5160, RSI=0x00000000124f15c0, RDI=0x0000000000002000
R8 =0x0000800080000000, R9 =0x0000000014889e58, R10=0x0000000000007378,   R11=0x00000000c04570f8
R12=0x00000000c0443200, R13=0x0000000000000a00, R14=0x00000000c04409f0,       R15=0x0000000000000ad8
RIP=0x0000000002990719, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246
```

And keeps going

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you have broken something. What are you actually using this for and what os?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500378/exception-access-violation-java

Comment: Have you checked the full stack trace?

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer amateur programmer Thank you for the quick reply.  The OS is - Windows web server 2008 R2.  4.00 gb, 64-bit OS.  I am using this for web automation scripts to test web apps.  How can I check out the full stack trace? I checked the dump log and could not make much of it.  Thanks again.